# How I insert and get values to and from database using Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How I insert my username, Password values to database using Zend framework.

And how I get the values from the database using zend framework.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any knowledge of working with databases in PHP? you should definitely [start there](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/index.html) before jumping into frameworks. When you have the basic understanding of how PHP and databases interact, transitioning that into a good framework like Zend's should not be too difficult.

The Zend Framework manual has a pretty comprehensive overview on [everything it can do with databases](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html).

Answer (score 5):

/**Insert**/
/**
* I assume that you are passing data through controller 
*/

```
class Application_Model_YourModelName extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

private static $_instance = null;
protected $_name = 'YourModelName';

public static function getinstance() {
    if (self::$_instance == null)
        self::$_instance = new Application_Model_YourModelName();
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function insertFunction(){
  if(func_num_args()>0){
      $userName = func_get_arg(0); // or some index if wanna pass through key value pair
     $password = md5(func_get_arg(1));
       $data = array('userName'=>$userName, 'password'=>$password);
         $insert = $this->insert($data);
  }
}


public function fetchFunction(){
  $sql = $this->select()
       ->where("*Your condition*")
       ;
   $result = $this->getAdapter->fetchAll(sql);
}
```

On the security front using md5 function is not safe enough, u might want to look for bcrypt hashing algorithm..
Here is the link for the same : 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html

Comment: Try this after skeleton set up. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
*
*To insert your values
*
* Here $uname and $password are values dynamically
*/

$db = new Zend_Db(....);
$data = array(
              'vUserName'=>$uname,
              'vPassword'=>md5($pwd)
);

$db->insert('tablename',$data);


/*
* 
*To get the values 
*
*/

$sql = "SELECT * FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE vUserName = '".$uname."'";
$data = $db->fetchAll($sql);
return $data;
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new Zend_Db(....);
$data = array('username'=>'thomaschaaf', 'password'= md5('secret'));
$db->insert('field', $data);
```